# Is there a way to intercept browser calls in node?

Tags: node.js

My app was hosted in xxx.com, which gets data from yyy.com. All API requests were triggered from client side.

Is there a way to intercept its request or response in node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, and Yes.**

For the requests made by your client, you must have some control of the data sent back to the client in order to intercept it.

Assume a scenario where:

> Client -----(request)----->Third Party App Server -------(response)-----> Client

In this case, as the back-end server never had a chance to come into picture, there is no way the server can change the data. Well of course, that is when the server doesn't come into picture.

Instead, if you send the request to the node server itself, which forwards the request to the Third Party App server, you obviously have control of the response receive and thus, you can manipulate both request and response or maybe just log it (whatever is your use case).

> Client -----(request)----->NODE_SERVER---->Third Party App Server -------(response)-----> Node_Server ----> Client

What a few developers do to intercept the requests made from the client is that they write some client-side JavaScript code and embed it into the browser (Some sort of authentication).
While this works okay in case of normal requests, a person with malicious intents might just disable your front-end interception code and directly receive a response from the Third Party application.

Thus, if you really need to have access to the requests and response, 
**YOU MUST FORWARD THE REQUESTS TO AN APP SERVER YOU HAVE CONTROL TO**.

**P.S.** It is not just about nodejs.